# compiler behaving abnormally for make

Tags: makefile

there is a very strange question about **makefile**, please let me describe it:

There are two files in my project, one file is **makefile**, the content of **makefile** is as follows:

```
context::
    @echo "hello makefile"
```

and the other is **makefile.out**, the content of the **makefile.out** file is as follows:

```
all:
    echo "hello makefile.out"
```

When I am going to compile my project, I will use `make -f makefile.out` to replace the `make` operation, because I want to call the **makefile.out** file, but it is strange What happened, when I executed `make -f makefile.out`, I would see such an operation on the console:

```
cp Makefile Makefile.out
hello makefile
```

and then my makefile.out file was modified as follows:

```
############################################################################
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.  The
# ASF licenses this file to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the
# License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
# WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.  See the
# License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#
############################################################################/


context::
    @echo "hello makefile"
```

As you have seen, this result is not I want it, but I don't know why this problem occurs.

I don’t know if anyone has encountered a similar problem with me. If so, can you tell me the solution code?

Comment: What version of Make are you using? (Try `make -v`)

Comment: Are you sure you're running `make` from the directory that contains the files you describe?

Comment: I do not reproduce this with GNU Make 4.0.  I am not prepared to believe that any conforming `make` implementation exhibits the behavior described when working from a makefile whose complete contents are as described in the question for *either* of the two makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know why this happened.

First, there's a built-in rule for GNU make that shows how to build a `%.out` file from a `%` file; `make -p` will show:

```
%.out: %
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        @rm -f $@
         cp $< $@
```

Second, make will always try to rebuild any makefile that it loads or includes; see the [How Makefiles are Remade](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html) section of the GNU make manual.

So every time you run `make -f makefile.out`, then *IF* (and only if) the `makefile` is newer than `makefile.out`, make will copy `makefile` to `makefile.out`.

You can avoid this in one of a number of ways: any **one** of the following will solve the problem:

First and probably the best is to avoid having any important file in your system named with a `.out` suffix.  That suffix is traditionally used for log files, output files, etc.  There are many environments where those files are treated as temporary by default.  It's just a bad name.

Second, you could create an explicit rule for `makefile.out` which would override the pattern rule:

```
makefile.out: ;
```

Third, you can remove that default rule by adding this to your makefile:

```
%.out: %
```

(no other prerequisites, no recipe).  See [Canceling Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html).

Fourth, you could remove ALL built-in pattern rules by adding the `-r` option to your `MAKEFLAGS`; add it to your makefile like this:

```
MAKEFLAGS += -r
```

Note this solution requires GNU make 4.0 or better.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, it has solved my problem perfectly.